# Mac can connect to samba via IP but not netbios name

Tags: samba, netbios, smb-conf

I've setup a samba share on Centos 6.

smb.conf

```
[data]
path = /data
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
valid users = user01
create mask = 0777
create mode = 0777
directory mode = 0777
share modes = yes
veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/
delete veto files = yes
```

chkconfig smb on
chkconfig nmb on
iptables off
selinux disabled

On my mac 10.10 using Finder, I can only connect it via IP

> smb://192.168.0.1/share

I pinged the hostname and it is resolving to the correct IP address. But I can't connect using the hostname of the server. It says The Share does not exist on the server. Please check the share name, and then try again.

Then on I tried it on a Windows machine, both //ipaddress and //hostname is working fine.

Further test seems to be that it is Finder in 10.10 causing an issue. I tried 10.9 and seems to mount the smb fine....

edit: tried from another 10.10 machine and it is fine. So just something wrong with this Finder on this particular mac. Will close the question.

Comment: I tried mounting the netbios name in terminal on the mac and it is fine. Seems to be a Finder issue?

Comment: This is more of a mac question than server one. But, at least provide us the logs (samba).

Comment: @KonradGajewski I thought it was a smb config issue in the beginning. But further test shows it is the mac so I want to close this question off.